# Diferencia entre caridad y generosidad

Tags: significado, diferencias-entre-palabras

No me queda muy claro esta diferencia. Estuve buscando pero encuentro cosas relacionadas con la religión y me gustaría algo que no este relacionado con este aspecto para diferenciar estos dos conceptos.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Por razones históricas es esperable que encuentres que la diferencia entre “caridad” y “generosidad” es explicada con referencias a la religión cristiana.

La palabra *caridad* tiene un par de significados muy diferentes pero relacionados. Por un lado, la caridad es una virtud cristiana que consiste en el amor a Dios y al prójimo. Por el otro lado es la práctica de dar ayuda a quienes la necesitan. Debido al abuso de la caridad como práctica (tanto de quienes la practican como, a veces, de quienes la solicitan), a veces la palabra es peyorativa, es decir, tiene un sentido negativo, asociado a la limosna y al asistencialismo, al deseo de figurar y de compensar por los pecados propios. La caridad como práctica aparece hoy muchas veces como institucionalizada, y el descrédito de la Iglesia y de las organizaciones que se llaman a sí mismas “caritativas” empeora la connotación de la palabra. (Esto no es un juicio personal mío sobre la caridad como concepto cristiano. Sólo digo cómo se percibe públicamente este concepto.)

La palabra *generosidad* por otro lado se percibe como una virtud y una práctica individual, no atada a ideas religiosas de ningún tipo, y también como una virtud social. Se puede decir que una sociedad es *generosa* cuando sus miembros son generosos entre sí y con los demás (por ejemplo, dando albergue a refugiados). La idea de *generosidad* no se asocia tanto como la caridad a una relación entre ricos y pobres, entre pudientes y necesitados.

En términos léxicos, se puede decir *organización caritativa* pero no *organización generosa*; la generosidad no se entiende como algo que pueda organizarse o planearse sino que surge de manera espontánea de un individuo.

Answer (score 6):

Las connotaciones que han adquirido las dos palabras debido a su uso están muy bien explicadas en la [respuesta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/34923/24236) de [pablodf76](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/14627/pablodf76). Esta respuesta se concentra en la diferencia puramente léxica. El DLE define [*caridad*](https://dle.rae.es/caridad) como

> 1. f. Actitud solidaria con el sufrimiento ajeno.

Para *generosidad* hay que investigar un poco más: la [*generosidad*](https://dle.rae.es/generosidad) viene definida en el DLE como *cualidad de generoso*, a su vez [*generoso*](https://dle.rae.es/generoso) es [*dadivoso*](https://dle.rae.es/dadivoso), que a su vez significa *propenso a hacer dádivas*, y finalmente [*dádiva*](https://dle.rae.es/d%C3%A1diva) significa

> 1. f. Acción de dar gratuitamente.

Como se ve, la principal diferencia es que la caridad implica la ayuda a alguien que **"sufre"**, o que **"necesita"** esa ayuda, mientras que la generosidad no tiene este requisito. Por ejemplo, una persona que invita a sus amigos a comer con frecuencia es *generosa*, pero no es *caritativa*.